# Why do I have to convert this?(StringToNative)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, c++-cli, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

This is part of a speech recognition project using the Google speech to text api. And I don't know what this code does. Do you know any friends?

```
ref class Converters {
  public:
    static size_t ConvertStringToNative(System::String^ string, wchar_t* native, size_t length) {
      size_t sizeInChar = string->Length;
      if (native == nullptr || sizeInChar > length) {
        return sizeInChar;
      }
      else {
        pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(string);
        memcpy_s(native, length * sizeof(wchar_t), wch, sizeInChar * sizeof(wchar_t)); 
        return sizeInChar;
      }
    }
    static array<System::Byte>^ ConvertArrayToManaged(void* value, size_t length) {
      auto bytes = gcnew array<System::Byte>(length);
      Marshal::Copy((System::IntPtr)value, bytes, 0, length);
      return bytes;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is this C++/CLI? Might be worth tagging that because stuff like `System::String^` is not standard C++.

Answer (score -1):

This class has Two static methods (Doesn't require object to call)

Method 1
size_t ConvertStringToNative(System::String^ string, wchar_t* native, size_t length)

1. This will take String object as parameter.
2. Extract characters from the String object.
3. Allocate memory for wchar_t of the size of characters within String object.
4. Copy the characters from String object to wchar_t
5. Return the pointer to wchar_t

Method 2
arraySystem::Byte^ ConvertArrayToManaged(void* value, size_t length)

1. This will create Managed object using character pointer

conversion is useful to convert datatype from one type to another so that data can sent to API in the format it accepts.